# Access two services methods from one controller in hibernate and Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, controller, mapping, netbeans6.7

I am stuck with access 2 services methods from one controller. I want to create a Task but same time I want to create new Role and assign its auto increment id to Task's roleId(foreign key). It is a one to one mapping.

Can I implement that in simpleFormContrller? And how can I do it?

`public class CreateTaskController extends SimpleFormController {`

```
 HResourceService hrService;         // Create a Service class instance.

 public void setHResourceService(HResourceService hrservice) {
    this.hrService = hrservice;
}

public CreateTaskController() {

    setCommandClass(Task.class);
        `
```

` @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {

```
    Task task = (Task) command;

    //ContactService.createContact(contact);

    hrService.createTask(task);

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    mv.setViewName(getSuccessView());

    mv.addObject("taskCreated", task.getDescription());    // Pass response to taskCreated view
    return mv;
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem if you have correct relation definition between hibernate beans.

```
public class Role implements Serializable {

   @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="task")    
   private Task task;

}

public class Task implements Serializable {
....
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,"role_id")
   private Role role;
....
}

@Override protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {

    Task task = (Task) command;
    task.setRole(new Role("big_brother").setTask(task));

    hrService.createTask(task);

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    mv.setViewName(getSuccessView());

    mv.addObject("taskCreated", task.getDescription());    // Pass response to taskCreated view
    return mv;
}
```